# Tenho dúvidas se essa seria a forma correta de fazer uma conexão utilizando a class PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com dúvida se essa forma é realmente correta de fazer uma conexão entre php e mysql com a class PDO. A dúvida é a seguinte: Cada vez que eu tiver uma arquivo que utilize essa conexão ele vai criar uma nova conexão

```
Class PDOUtil {

public static final function conectar() {
    try {
        $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site_local', 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();

        if ($ex->getCode() == "2002") {
            echo 'Oi infelizmente seu Host nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
        }
        if ($ex->getCode() == "1049") {
            echo 'Oi infelizmente seu banco nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
        }
        if ($ex->getCode() == "1044") {
            echo 'Oi infelizmente seu usuario nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
        }
        if ($ex->getCode() == "1045") {
            echo 'Oi infelizmente sua senha nao foi encontrada, verifique isso com o web-master.';
        }
    }
    return $conexao;
}
```

}

um exemplo de utilização

```
include '../config/PDOUtil.php';
$con = new PDOUtil();
$con->conectar();
```

Comment: A sua classe conectar é estática, então não há necessidade de instanciar um objeto. Esse é um padrão chamado singleton você poderia simplesmente chamar ela usando $con = PDOUtil::conectar(); A partir daí é só usar o objeto do PDO. $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela"); $con->execute(); $retorno = $con->fetchAll(); E por ai vai.

Answer (score 3):

Seu script está certo, porem vai ficar criando uma conexão nova a cada vez que você solicitar. Tente desta forma, utilizando o padrão [Singleton](http://www.devmedia.com.br/php-singleton-aplicando-o-padrao-de-projeto-na-pratica/28469);

```
Class PDOUtil {
private static $oInstance;

public static function getConexao() {

  if (!(self::$oInstance instanceof PDO)) {
    try {
      $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site_local', 'root', '');
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();

      if ($ex->getCode() == "2002") {
        echo 'Oi infelizmente seu Host nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
      }

      if ($ex->getCode() == "1049") {
        echo 'Oi infelizmente seu banco nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
      }

      if ($ex->getCode() == "1044") {
        echo 'Oi infelizmente seu usuario nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
      }

      if ($ex->getCode() == "1045") {
        echo 'Oi infelizmente sua senha nao foi encontrada, verifique isso com o web-master.';
      }
      exit;
    }

  }
  return self::$oInstance;
}

/* TORNA O CONSTRUTOR PRIVADO PARA PROIBIR DE INSTANCIA ESTA CLASSE */
private function __construct() {}

}
```

Para utilizar agora você sempre pode fazer desta forma:

```
$conexao = PDOUtil::getConexao();
```

Desta forma somente uma conexão vai existir na sua aplicação e você consegue pegar a mesma facilmente;

Answer (score 1):

Em PDO você só precisa de uma conexão para toda a "existência" do script, exatamente igual faria com mysql_*.

```
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example-pdo', 'andre', '123456',
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    )
);
```

No exemplo acima, configuramos nossa conexão como persistente. Uma conexão persistente não é fechada no final do script, e sim armazenada em cache sendo reutilizada quando outro script solicitar uma conexão usando as mesmas credenciais.

**A sua forma está correta!**